# Attribute error in pandas for a column that exists

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with Pandas for the first time and I ran into an issue that's really stumping me.  I'm trying to reference a column of a dataframe, but I'm getting an error.  The weird thing is that I can reference the column in other parts of my code no problem but not others.

Here's my code:

```
loops = 0
instability = sys.maxsize
print(team_seasons['season']) #this works
while loops < 1000 and instability > 12000:
    for game in df_reg.itertuples():
        if game.Season == 2016:
            #weight so that late season results are about twice as valueable as early season
            weight = (game.Daynum + 60)/192
            Wrating = team_seasons.loc[(team_seasons['season']==game.season) & (team_seasons['Team_Id']==game.Wteam),'rating']
            Lrating = team_seasons.loc[(team_seasons['season']==game.season) & (team_seasons['Team_Id']==game.Lteam),'rating']
            Wres,Lres = calc_rating(Wrating,Lrating,game.Wscore,game.Lscore)
            print(Wres,Lres)
            break
    break
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute 'season'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-eacf72e4fe01> in <module>()
      8             #weight so that late season results are about twice as valueable as early season
      9             weight = (game.Daynum + 60)/192
---> 10             Wrating = team_seasons.loc[(team_seasons['season']==game.season) & (team_seasons['Team_Id']==game.Wteam),'rating']
     11             Lrating = team_seasons.loc[(team_seasons['season']==game.season) & (team_seasons['Team_Id']==game.Lteam),'rating']
     12             Wres,Lres = calc_rating(Wrating,Lrating,game.Wscore,game.Lscore)

AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute 'season'
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?  Is it because I'm trying to reference the column within a loc statement?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe need change `game.season` to `game.Season`

Comment: Look at `game.columns`. Is `season` on the list? If it is not, find out what the right name is.